# Lambda function does not compile with different signature

Tags: c++, lambda

I am trying out c++ lambda functions:

This works:

```
std::function<std::string(std::string)>lambda = [] (std::string message) -> std::string
   {
       return std::string("test");
   };
```

i can call the function with `std::cout << lambda(std::string("in"));`, and it prints `"test"`.

however if i pass another type (`std::istream`) it wont compile. A mapping from `std::istream` to any type, for example string should be the final goal. I'm going to use templates for this purpose. :

```
std::function<std::string(std::istream)>lambda = [] (std::istream message) -> std::string
   {
       return std::string("test");
   };
```

This is the output from g++:

```
g++ -I"/home/***/workspace.cpp/unrealcv-renderer/include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/unrealcv_renderer.d" -MT"src/unrealcv_renderer.o" -o "src/unrealcv_renderer.o" "../src/unrealcv_renderer.cpp"
../src/unrealcv_renderer.cpp: In constructor ‘event_camera_simulator::UnrealCVRenderer::UnrealCVRenderer(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string)’:
../src/unrealcv_renderer.cpp:23:8: error: conversion from ‘event_camera_simulator::UnrealCVRenderer::UnrealCVRenderer(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string)::<lambda(std::istream)>’ to non-scalar type ‘std::function<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>(std::basic_istream<char>)>’ requested
        };
        ^
```

What is causing trouble here?

Comment: Lambdas are irrelevant. This doesn't compile with a regular function either.

Comment: Compiler errors regarding instantiation can be confusing because it's second pass of translation..it's good to know  class capabilities or check it in documentation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you pass the `std::istream` by value, which possibly necessitates a copy, and that is a [non-copy-able class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/basic_istream).

A possible solution would be to accept by reference instead:

```
std::function<std::string(std::istream&)>lambda = [] (std::istream& message) -> std::string
   {
       return std::string("test");
   };
```

Comment: looks like four people tried to write same question.  XD